# Check radio button with label that contained link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to check the radio button with clicking on label and it works. but when i use a link tag in my label and click on the link that is in the label my radio button don't check.

I don't use of any jquery code for this problem and it's just a html code that don't work correctly.

you can test it below:

```css
a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-ctn">
  <label class="btn05 active">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Male</span>
    <a href="#">sample link that I want to click on it and radio be selected... </a>
  </label>
  <label class="btn05">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Female</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The real question is why on earth you'd use an anchor inside a label

Comment: Should this be a actual link or do you just want to style it like a link?

Comment: Anyway -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gpvbtf50/1/

Comment: that is right...
that link is for show more details in another page
and main issue is using radio button correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/nvce3w4j/

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
   $(this).parent().find('input').prop('checked', 'checked');
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-ctn">
  <label class="btn05 active">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Male</span>
    <a href="#">sample link that I want to click on it and radio be selected... </a>
  </label>
  <label class="btn05">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Female</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can remove (href="#") attribute like this code

```
   <div class="radio-ctn">
        <label class="btn05 active">
            <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Male</span>
            <a>Click her to check</a>
        </label>
        <label class="btn05">
            <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Female</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

or use jQuery event

```js
$('.check_gender').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="radio-ctn">
        <label class="btn05 active">
            <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Male</span>
            <a href="#" class="check_gender">Click her to check</a>
        </label>
        <label class="btn05">
            <input type="radio" name="gender"><span>Female</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want to use the link with href